# How to split string with unique substrings JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

How to split in JavaScript string like `"somestring\correct{s}\wrong{g}somestring\correct{w}somestring"` to array like `["somestring", "\correct{s}", "\wrong{g}", "somestring", "\correct{w}", "somestring"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.match`:

```
var arr = str.match(/\\?[a-z]+(?:\{[a-z]\})?/g)
```

Should work!

[image: console screenshot]